# How to apply REST API to webserver

Tags: mysql, spring, webserver

I have a webserver running on my old laptop, which I used for a homepage. Now I set up an MySQL database on the server and want to get the data over a Spring REST API. If I run the rest on localhost it works.
Now my question is do I have to bind the rest to the servers IP address or how do I make it accessible to the outside?

Im using an Ubuntu Server. Created an apache server. Installed MySQL(-server) and created a database. Made a Spring REST which returns values of users when requested IP/user. Now I wanted to made the access puplic (from other machines / IP adresses).
Im really new to this and don't know if I have to add something and or change something in the properties.

My applicaton.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user_db
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug

logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57InnoDBDialect

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect.storage_engine=innodb
```

Comment: you should put a bit more details on your environment and technologies used

Comment: Hello Dunkelbunt, and welcome to StackOverflow! REST and accessibility are two different things. On one end, REST means the way that you structure your API, while the accessibility of your server is dependant on the network setup. I suggest that you consult a beginner's guide to understanding Spring, and work your way up. https://www.baeldung.com/rest-with-spring-series provides a good place to start and I suggest that you look into JPA and Spring Repositories as a next step.